# form submit in codeigniter going to blank page

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am submitting form using form helpers and it's going to blank page and when I see the view source, the action in the view source is like this `http://::1/ci1/login_validation` I don't understand the `::1` in it shouldn't it be `localhost:8080/`? But if I use simple form tags like regular html it works fine?

```
<?php   
echo form_open ('login_validation');    
echo form_input('email');
echo form_password('password');
echo form_submit('login_submit', 'login');  
echo  form_close(); 
?>
```

View Source

```
<form action="http://::1/ci1/login_validation" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 

<p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="" /></p>

<p>Password:<input type="password" name="password" value="" /></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="login" /></p>

</form>
```

Comment: Show us the HTML you get from those echos.

Comment: Your form code that you have in comment should of been edited on question by clicking on edit button below tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think it is a couple of thing like.

If your form action has `http://::1/` then does not submit correct because base url is empty

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Fill base url example:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name/';
```

On codeigniter 3 version not best idea to leave it blank because you will run in to that issue.

Make sure your class and file names of controllers etc have first letter upper case.

**Filename:** Login_validation.php

Controller:

```
<?php

class Login_validation extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

     // form submit controller code.

}

}
```

View

```
<?php   
echo form_open ('login_validation');    
echo form_input('email');
echo form_password('password');
echo form_submit('login_submit', 'login');  
echo form_close(); 
?>
```

This is a common mistake people for get to check.

Answer (score 0):

**Why `http://::1/`??**

This mean your `base_url()` is empty.

---

**Then how this `http://::1/` comes??**

When your project URL is empty, CI detect your project URL. So this `http://::1/` knows your project path.

---

**How to set `base_url()`??**

In `config/config.php` set `$config['base_url'] = '';` the project URL.

---

**Keeping `base_url()` empty any harm??**

When you in local its ok and fine. But when you host that just add your site URL to it.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
```