# echo form_open('user_authentication/new_user_registration'); rendered wrong url

Tags: codeigniter

I have problem about the form_open or any url in my site, maybe this is the new update of codeigniter or what. when I use  its rendered a confusing syntax like http://::1/ and my form not working correctly or take me to  a blank page. also my css dont work.

here is my php code.

```
<html>
<?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {

header("location: http://localhost/login/index.php/user_authentication/user_login_process");
}
?>
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($logout_message)) {
echo "<div class='message'>";
echo $logout_message;
echo "</div>";
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($message_display)) {
echo "<div class='message'>";
echo $message_display;
echo "</div>";
}
?>
<div id="main">
<div id="login">
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<hr/>
<?php echo form_open('user_authentication/user_login_process'); ?>
<?php
echo "<div class='error_msg'>";
if (isset($error_message)) {
echo $error_message;
}
echo validation_errors();
echo "</div>";
?>
<label>UserName :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="username"/><br /><br />
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="**********"/><br/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Login " name="submit"/><br />
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/user_authentication/user_registration_show">To SignUp Click Here</a>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then here is the view page source. im using google chrome browser

```
<html>
    <head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://::1/login/css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="main">
<div id="login">
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<hr/>
<form action="http://::1/login/index.php/user_authentication/user_login_process" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class='error_msg'></div>   <label>UserName :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="username"/><br /><br />
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="**********"/><br/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Login " name="submit"/><br />
<a href="http://::1/login/index.php/user_authentication/user_registration_show">To SignUp Click Here</a>
</form> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the url of css and form are rendered a wrong url. href="http://::1/login/css/style.css"> instead of  href="css/style.css">. also the form_open(). whats wrong with this?

Comment: What's the value of `$config['base_url']`in config/config.php?

Comment: Try setting it explicitly: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Comment: im using localhost and my website folder is login so my base_url is http://localhost/login. Am  I right?

Comment: base_url should be `http://localhost/login/`yes.

Comment: oh... that's work.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> > **Its because of your base_url is empty**

---

**How to set `base_url()`??**

In `config/config.php` set `$config['base_url'] = '';` the project URL.

---

**Keeping `base_url()` empty any harm??**

When you in local its ok and fine. But when you host that just add your site URL to it.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
```

---

[Take look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478457/4595675)

and Possible duplicate of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476293/form-submit-in-codeigniter-going-to-blank-page/34478457#34478457)

Comment: Never forget the scheme nor trailing slash (i.e. `http://www.stackoverflow.com/`) because that way you will avoid issues using url helper functions. Sometimes, if scheme is not there, url helper functions duplicate url string so you get soemthing like `www.example.com/www.example.com/method/arg`. [Docs and comments](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php).